# JRebel and Maven plugin setup for IntelliJ - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, permgen, appfuse, jrebel

Can anyone help?
I am using Appfuse archetype project in IDEA with maven and JRebel plugins. Below is what I am getting when I run jetty:run from the Maven Projects in Idea. I increased MAVEN_OPTS in /etc/launchd.conf (MAC) and added added -XX:MaxPermSize=128m to the maven plugin Runner in IDEA as VM option. What else can I do to fix it? Thanks.

2011-12-16 17:49:16.877:INFO:/:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
JRebel-Spring: Monitoring Spring bean definitions in '/Users/vraskin/projects/appfuse_projects/test_project/tutorial/tutorial-spring/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml'.
ERROR [main] Digester.startElement(1366) | Begin event threw error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

...

2011-12-16 17:49:25.310:WARN::failed dispatcher: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:25.310:WARN::failed org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@4dd3c6fd{/,/Users/vraskin/projects/appfuse_projects/test_project/tutorial/tutorial-spring/src/main/webapp}: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:25.310:WARN::failed ContextHandlerCollection@2442c1ad: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:25.310:WARN::failed HandlerCollection@1ab95774: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:25.310:WARN::Error starting handlers
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:26.152:WARN::failed org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector$1@12d37bd8: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:26.152:WARN::failed SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2011-12-16 17:49:26.152:WARN::failed Server@3dd510be: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.

...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: Did you run maven from command line after exporting the MAVEN_OPTS.? Did you still get this error ? (just trying to narrow down the problem)

Comment: It is starting fine when I run mvn jetty:run from the terminal, and I am able to see the page on localhost:8080

Comment: Just figured out. 
This error is related to the fact that I am running it with "Run with JRebel ... " option from IDEA, as discribed in AppFuse environment setup. However, if you run it without JRebel, just Run With Maven Build, then it works fine.